# Construct JSON object with symfony 1.4, with a field with html content

Tags: php, jquery, symfony-1.4, json

I've seen some question here about almost the same thing, but, after following their suggestions I keep getting the same behavior.

I'm constructing the json object in my action as follows:

```
return $this->renderText(json_encode(array(
            'html'  => addslashes($this->renderPartial('global/formWrapper',
                    array(
                        'form'  => $nareas,
                        'url'   => $this->generateUrl('new_promo_step2'),
                        'cancelUrl' => 'new_promo',
                          ))),
            'error' => true)));
```

and Im getting the following response:

```
<html>
  The html content which is supposed to be in the "html" property of my json
  object...
</html>{"html":"None","error":true}
```

along with a header with a `Content-Type:text/html; charset=utf-8`.

In my jQuery ajax request, I've set the dataType as 'json' (and of course I get an unexpected character error), and as 'text' (and I get no error, but keep getting the malformed json)

I've tried using `addslashes()` (as in the example), and without this function; tried using the `ESC_RAW` symfony option, and got the same.

I'm expecting to get something like this:

```
{"html":"<html>Html content</html>","error":true}
```

Please! any help would be strongly appreciated!

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To render a partial from the action you will need to load your partials as an include and use getPartial to retrieve it into your renderText call.

```
sfLoader::loadHelpers('Partial');
return $this->renderText(json_encode(array(
        'html'  => addslashes(getPartial('global/formWrapper',
                array(
                    'form'  => $nareas,
                    'url'   => $this->generateUrl('new_promo_step2'),
                    'cancelUrl' => 'new_promo',
                      ))),
        'error' => true)));
```